# Producing XML with NodeValues from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to produce XML from SQL Server, and need the field I'm selecting to be in the nodevalue rather than an attribute.

My current SQL is:-

> SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account FOR XML AUTO

which then produces XML like:-

```
<Account AccountNumber="12345" />
```

where I'd like it to appear as:-

```
<AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

You should also check out the `FOR XML PATH(...),ROOT(....)` construct available in SQL Server 2008 and newer: [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx)

This would allow you to

- specify a root node for a number of XML elements
- specify the XML tag names
- specify certain bits as XML attributes

So in your case, you could e.g. create something like:

```
SELECT
    AccountNumber, AcctID AS '@AcctID',
    AccountHolder
FROM
    dbo.Accounts
FOR XML PATH('Account'), ROOT('AllAccounts')
```

and you would get something like this as your output:

```
<AllAccounts>
   <Account AcctID="42">
      <AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
      <AccountHolder>John Doe</AccountHolder>
   </Account> 
   <Account AcctID="4711">
      <AccountNumber>54321</AccountNumber>
      <AccountHolder>Jane Willis-Doe</AccountHolder>
   </Account> 
   ..... (possibly more <Account> elements) ......
</AllAccounts>
```

With the `FOR XML PATH` method, you can very easily fine-tune what your resulting XML should look like.

Answer (score 2):

add ELEMENTS to the end:

```
SELECT AccountNumber FROM Account FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```